# How effective is deviated septum surgical procedure?

Tags: nose, ears-nose-throat-ent, deviated-nasal-septum

I got back from an ENT specialist yesterday due my nose always being blocked up. I've tried everything from patches, prescription bills, nasal sprays and nothing seemed to help! He prescribed me a different nasal spray and again, was not effective. He did say my septum was deviated to the left. How effective is this surgery at fixing nose blockage? Is it minimally invasive?

Comment: It's interesting that you say you have tried "everything" but it seems you did not try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_irrigation   Could it be that things that don't cost much are not being recommended to you or would that be cynical?

Answer (score 2):

According to the article [How is deviated nasal septum related to cold](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/how-is-deviated-nasal-septum-related-to-cold):

> By looking at the information above you could think that the connection between nasal septum deviation and chronic sinusitis is clear. This literary review however states that the correlation between a deviated nasal septum and having chronic sinusitis is still unclear.

So it looks like it is unclear whether it will help you reduce the risk of infection, but it also looks like it is a given that it will improve your breathing