# Permanent stuffy nose...?

Tags: breathing, nose

I've been to four ENT's and most just prescribe me medication and spend 5 minutes talking to me and leave. I've tried nasal sprays, pills, patches and no luck. My latest ENT doctor told me I had a deviated septum and despite me telling him I've tried nasal sprays he still prescribed me some! (Dymesta) Big surprise, it lasted a couple of minutes and I was back to square one again. Is there a surgical procedure for this? I feel this is the only solution for me at this point

Comment: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/how-effective-is-deviated-septum-surgical-procedure

Comment: Have you made a conscious effort to stay hydrated? It sounds to me that you are not drinking enough water.

Answer (score 1):

I remember adolescents getting nose jobs for their deviated septums.  I am surprised that all the doctors did not mention the deviated septum.  Have you explored the realm of allergies?

I had been, most of my life, getting head colds in which I could not breathe.  My nose also got stuffy frequently.  I took antihistamines and decongestants and whatever I could.  I thought it was just a genetic anomaly, as my father had the same problem.

Dr. Oz, whom I do not watch regularly, recommended a neti pot.  I bought one (sold in drug stores and my local supermarket).  There is probably a utube on using it.  I am amazed at how well this works.  I actually get fewer colds.  I used this thing daily for a month and it seems to have cleared out a lingering condition because I hardly have to use it any longer.  I am not kidding.  This thing changed my life.

The only caveat is that you should make sure your water has been pre boiled as a woman seems to have caught a brain ameba through the water system by using this thing.  I just boil extra water in the teapot when I make tea and it's cool enough (I even use it at room temp) by the time I use it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, adults can receive surgery for a deviated septum. All surgeries have recovery time and [the potential for complications](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/septoplasty/details/risks/cmc-20205422), and this one does not resolve symptoms 100% of the time. Thus, good doctors will want to be sure you've made good, solid tries on everything else first.

To explore surgery as an option, the following will help:

- Make a list of everything you've tried (especially past medications, but also past home remedies), and for how many days you tried them.
- When scheduling with an ENT, ask their nurse if the physician performs surgery for deviated septum

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying laser sinus therapy. This technology has been used in Russia for decades and has finally made it to the United States. Unfortunately, many U.S. doctors are still unaware of it.